# How to include test classes into shadowJar?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, gradle, shadowjar

I am using shadow Gradle plugin to build JAR, containing all referenced jars inside.

In my `build.gradle` I have only

```
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
```

and

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MYCLASS'
    }

}
```

related to that. I don't know, how it knows, what to build, but it works.

Now, is it possible, to include test classes too?

Comment: Did you come up with any solution on this one?

Answer (score 4):

From the official documentation https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/custom-tasks/

> *Shadowing Test Sources and Dependencies*
>
> `import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
>   task testJar(type: ShadowJar) {
>    classifier = 'tests'
>    from sourceSets.test.output
>    configurations = [project.configurations.testRuntime]
>   }`
>
> The code snippet above will geneated a shadowed JAR contain both the main and test sources as well as all runtime and testRuntime dependencies. The file is output to build/libs/--tests.jar.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JAR is empty for me. There are neither dependencies nor source classes in it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Running the jar just outputs `Error: Could not find or load main class org.scalatest.tools.Runner`. Btw I have `dependencies { testRuntime "org.scalatest:scalatest_${scalaBinaryVersion}:3.0.5" }`.

Comment: @jirislav seeing that these are the official instructions on how to accomplish the task, I would advise you to visit the [plugin's github page](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) and open an issue there if necessary.

Comment: My tests get included but these won't include the main sources.

Answer (score 4):

The official documentation seems out of date with the latest (v7.0.0) version of the plugin. Using this version and the latest version of gradle (7.0), I do this:

```
task testJar(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar) {
    archiveClassifier.set("alltests")
    from sourceSets.main.output, sourceSets.test.output
    configurations = [project.configurations.testRuntimeClasspath]
}
```

The docs have both the `from` clause and the "configurations" clause wrong.

- as a comment on the other answer mentions, the main classes (whihc are normally your classes under test) are missing from the jar, so you need to add `sourceSets.main.output`
- the `project.configurations.testRuntime` doesn't work as documented, it tells me `testImplementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false`